# Do things move towards you or away from you in a black hole?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, event-horizon

If one is falling towards the singularity inside a black hole along with a collection of disconnected objects surrounding you, would they appear to move towards you (because everything is contracting and falling towards the singularity) or would they appear to be moving away from you (because of the differential acceleration)?

I'm inclined to think they'd appear to be moving away from you because that's how spaghettification happens, with one end of you being pulled in faster than the other end. But what about for objects that are at the same radial distance from the singularity as you are. Would they move away, get closer, or appear not to be moving?

Furthermore, if the answer is that things appear to move away from you, is that movement uniform in all directions? If you were surrounded by a cloud of dust falling in with you, if you looked in any direction would it all appear to be moving away from you at the same rate (proportional to the distance from you) for a sufficiently large black hole?

Comment: Spaghettification is an expansion in the longitudinal direction, and a contraction along the two transverse axes. This is true in any gravitational field, not just near a black hole.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer this question I will use the geodesic deviation equation. This describes the relative motion of two test masses separated by a vector $u^\alpha$. This equation is
$$
\frac{dU^\alpha}{ds}~+~R^\alpha_{\mu\beta\nu}V^\mu U^\beta V^\nu~=~0.
$$
For the Schwarzschild metric the Riemann curvature tensor components are
$$
R_{trtr}~=~-\frac{2mc^2}{r^3},~R_{t\theta t\theta }~=~\frac{(r~-~2m)mc^2}{r^2},~R_{t\phi t\phi }~=\frac{(r~-~2m)mc^2sin^2\theta}{r^2}
$$
$$
R_{r\theta r\theta}~=~-\frac{m}{r~-~2m},~R_{r\phi r\phi}~=~-\frac{m~sin^2\theta}{r~-~2m}, R_{\theta\phi\theta\phi}~=~2mr~sin^2\theta.
$$

We first consider the deviation between two masses separated by a radial distance so the geodesic deviation equation is
$$
\frac{dr}{ds}~+~g^{rr}(R_{rtrt}V^trV^t~+~R_{r\theta r\theta}V^\theta r V^\theta~+~R_{r\phi r\phi}V^\phi r V^\phi)~=~0.
$$
I also recognize that the first term in $O(c^2)$ larger, so I really only need to consider this term. For a frame falling at say the center of mass of the two test charges we can set $V^t~=~(1,~0,~0,~0)$ and reduce this differential equation to
$$
\frac{dr}{ds}~+~g^{rr}R_{rtrt}r~=~0,
$$
or
$$
\frac{dr}{ds}~-~\left(1~-~\frac{2m}{r}\right)\frac{2mc^2}{r^3}U^r~=~0.
$$
This is easily solved by recognizing
$$
\frac{\frac{dr}{ds}}{r}~=~\frac{d~lnr}{ds}~=~\left(1~-~\frac{2m}{r}\right)\frac{2mc^2}{r^3},
$$
It is then not hard to see that the radial vector is exponential in the proper interval $s$. Particularly near or in the black hole the separation is huge. This is the basis for so called spaghettification.

Now consider the separation of a vector by $\theta$ coordinate. The geodesic equation again has the relevant term $O(c^2)$ larger with
$$
\frac{d\theta}{ds}~=~-g^{\theta\theta}R_{\theta t\theta t}\theta^2~=~-r^2\frac{(r~-~2m)mc^2\theta^2}{r^2}.
$$
The actual distance between the test masses is of course is given by arclength $r\theta$. It is then not hard to see the distance decreases. This means a sphere of test masses falling radially into a black hole will elongate along the radial direction into an ellipsoid that quickly turns into a line of particles.

Comment: If I'm understanding this answer correctly, then the expansion of the observable universe is not consistent with being in a black hole because we should only see expansion along one axis, and contraction in other directions, but what we actually see is uniform expansion in all directions?

Comment: Good deduction. If the universe were  some huge black hole we would see galaxies red shifted along some azimuthal direction. Off that direction the red shift factor would decrease and then galaxies on the plane perpendicular to this axis would be in fact blue shifted.

Comment: That deduction was all I was trying to confirm or deny with a previous question but it got marked as a duplicate of a question which didn't actually address my question :/ https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/354419/is-the-expansion-of-the-universe-really-evidence-against-the-universe-being-insi